# numpy.linalg.eig does not find obvious eigen vector

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra

I have a matrix `A` as below:

```
A
Out[34]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I want to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Consider a vector `x` as below:

```
x
Out[35]: array([4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

This is an eigenvector as can be seen below:

```
np.matmul(A, x) == 4 * x
Out[36]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
(np.matmul(A, x) == 4 * x).all()
Out[37]: True
```

But, when I compute the eigenvectors using `np.linalg.eig`, it does not include x (or a scaled vector of x).

```
l, v = np.linalg.eig(A)

l
Out[40]: array([0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0.])


v
Out[41]: 
array([[-8.66025404e-01,  5.00000000e-01, -2.77555756e-17,
        -2.77555756e-17,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 2.88675135e-01,  5.00000000e-01, -5.77350269e-01,
        -5.77350269e-01,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 2.88675135e-01,  5.00000000e-01,  7.88675135e-01,
        -2.11324865e-01,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 2.88675135e-01,  5.00000000e-01, -2.11324865e-01,
         7.88675135e-01,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00, -8.66025404e-01,  5.00000000e-01,
        -2.77555756e-17, -2.77555756e-17],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.88675135e-01,  5.00000000e-01,
        -5.77350269e-01, -5.77350269e-01],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.88675135e-01,  5.00000000e-01,
         7.88675135e-01, -2.11324865e-01],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.88675135e-01,  5.00000000e-01,
        -2.11324865e-01,  7.88675135e-01]])
```

Though the eigenvalue 4 is included, the eigenvector is missing. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is correct. If you examine,

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

l, v = np.linalg.eig(A)

print(v[:, 1])
```

Gives `[0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.  0.  0.  0. ]` which is the eigen vector that is a scalar multiple of the vector that you are looking for. The function gives the normalized vector and that's why it's all 0.5 instead of 4. However, they are equivalent in this context.

Comment: I realized I was looking into the rows whereas I should have looked into the columns. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea why `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` is not listed as a eigenvector. It has eigenvalue 4.

Comment: Because that can be created using a linear combination of `[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, both of which also has an eigen value of 4.